# iOS: How do I add multiple progress bars with all showing progress

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

How do I add multiple progress bars programmatically with all showing uploading progress of file?

I am using

```
(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didSendBodyData:
(NSInteger)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(NSInteger)totalBytesWritten
totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(NSInteger)totalBytesExpectedToWrite
```

but I am not able to do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set the progress to UIProgressView when upload with NSURLConnection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12942464/set-the-progress-to-uiprogressview-when-upload-with-nsurlconnection)

Comment: What are you not able to do? What exactly isn't working? Can you show your code where you create your progress bars?

Comment: i am used UIprogressbar
and uplaoding image with NSURLConnection
but uplaoding multiple images and for that i need multiple progress bar on view.
if i create it programmatically i am not able to show its progress using 
(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didSendBodyData:(NSInteger)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(NSInteger)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(NSInteger)totalBytesExpectedToWrite

cos it need static progressbar name.
it may be very easy but idk how to do it. please help